# Can my computer support a graphics card alongside the APU?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, desktop-computer

So, until I can afford a better PC, by brother is letting me borrow his older PC to play games on. [The PC specs are here](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ULTRA-FAST-Quad-Core-16GB-1TB-Desktop-Gaming-PC-Computer-AMD-HD-4-2Ghz-/121377873194?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item1c42af5d2a).

The PC has an APU so you can imagine the graphics are lacking a bit for games that I want to play such as Arma 3.

This question is to ask if for one, the motherboard can support a standalone graphics card and what graphics card would you recommend me getting that is compatible with this set up that is capable of running arma 3.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Hardware recommendations are regarded as off topic on SU as they generally only benefit the person asking the question and are primarily opinion based.

Comment: However, as I have experience building a computer who's main purpose was to run Arma 3 and Battlefield 2 on a budget, I would recommend a 7850, or 650ti.

Comment: Thank you, would that be compatible with the setup?

Comment: Yes, if your APU supports mantle, I'd go for the 7850. Please note though that this build will not be future proof. If you wanted to play GTAV for instance, this build would not perform well. If you want a future proof build, go for an r9 280x or GTX 970.

Comment: Ok thank you, the PC is temporary till I can afford a proper gaming PC, a card just for Arma will do nicely, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: If you only want to run it at low resolution and want a cheap card you could get a 6870 or a 550ti or something like that. My previous recommendation was to run the game at fairly high settings at 1080p 45fps+. If it is just temporary, go to a local pawn store (CeX in UK) and pick up a cheap £50 card equivalent to a 6870.

Comment: The PSU is listed as "500 Watt" - if you look inside the computer can you see what brand it is? Does it have PCI Express power connectors, like [www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/question-on-my-psu-and-pci-6-2-pin-connector.202937/](http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/question-on-my-psu-and-pci-6-2-pin-connector.202937/)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your actual question is 'Yes you can put a regular PCIe graphics card in there'..

[Motherboard Spec](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5289#ov)

Anything else becomes a hardware recommendation & is therefore off-topic.